# Using the root test on power series when the limit does not exist

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I need to find radius and interval of convergence (and also of absolute convergence) of the following series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3+(-1)^n}{7+(-1)^n}\right)^nx^n$$

I've applied the root test:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{3+(-1)^n}{7+(-1)^n}\right)^nx^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{3+(-1)^n}{7+(-1)^n}\right)x=\left\{\frac{1}{2}x,\frac{1}{3}x\right\}$$

The limit doesn't exist: it oscillates between $\frac{x}{2}$ and $\frac{x}{3}$.

How do I proceed from here? What the root test tells in this case?

I think that in this case the series is convergent (and absolutely convergent) when $x=0$.

So, the radius of convergence is $0$ and the interval of convergence is $\{0\}$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim \sup |((\frac{3+(-1)^n}{7+(-1)^n})^{n}|^{1/n}=\frac 1 2$ so the radius of convergence is $2$.

Ref. for the formula for radius of converegnce of a power series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence

Comment: @geetha290km, why is it $\frac{3}{7}$ and not $\frac{1}{2}$? If radius of convergence is $\frac{3}{7}$, the series should converge when $x=\frac{3}{8}$ (because it is within radius of convergence), but it is not: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%28%283%2B%28-1%29%5En%29%2F%287%2B%28-1%29%5En%29%29%5En+%283%2F8%29%5En%2C+n%3D1..oo

Comment: Corrected. $\lim \sup$ is the larger of the two numbers $\frac 4 8$ and $\frac 2 6$. Note that $\frac 1 2  >\frac 1 3 $. @eMathHelp

Comment: If radius of convergence is $2$, the series should converge when $x=\frac{3}{8}$ (because it is within radius of convergence), but it is not: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%28%283%2B%28-1%29%5En%29%2F%287%2B%28-1%29%5En%29%29%5En+%283%2F8%29%5En%2C+n%3D1..oo

Comment: The series is absolutely convergent for $x=\frac 3 8$. In fact it is dominated by the geometric series $\sum (\frac 3 8)^{n}$.  WolframAlpha can be wrong. @eMathHelp

Comment: It is advisable to use the formula for convergence of a power series instead of directly applying root test. @eMathHelp

Comment: So wolframalpha is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, there are many complaints on MSE about mistakes on Mathematica and WorframAlpha @eMathHelp

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: what formula for convergence do you have in mind, when you say "It is advisable to use the formula for convergence of a power series instead of directly applying root test." ?